# How to change the color of the image that is selected?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

Currently, I have this product details component, so whenever I click on the image I want to add a className of "active", how can I achieve that with the current code? How do I look for the prev value and current value? So that I can remove the active class from the previous image and add it to the newly selected image, Any suggestion?

```
const ProductDetails = () => {
  const myRef = useRef();
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    products: [
      {
        _id: "1",
        title: "Nike Shoes",
        src: [
          "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2021/01/07/img2.png",
          "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2021/01/07/img3.png",
          "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2021/01/07/img4.png",
        ],
      },
    ],
    index: 0,
  });

  const { products, index } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    const { index } = state;
    myRef.current.children[0].className = "active";
  }, []);

  const handleTab = (index) => {
    // alert(index);
    setState({ products, index: index });

  };

  return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          {products.map((item) => (
            <Colsm6 key={item._id}>
              <ProductdetailsPic>
                <Sync1>
                  <Item>
                    <img src={item.src[index]} alt="" />
                  </Item>
                </Sync1>
                <Sync2>
                  {item.src.map((img, indx) => (
                    <Item ref={myRef}>
                      <Itempro>
                        <img
                          src={img}
                          alt="img"
                          onClick={() => handleTab(indx)}
                        />
                      </Itempro>
                    </Item>
                  ))}
                </Sync2>
              </ProductdetailsPic>
            </Colsm6>
          ))}
          <Prosdetleft></Prosdetleft>
        </Row>
      </Container>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

Comment: Have you tried css pseudo `:focus` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already store the active `index` in your state so you can use that. Although I would move that out and use a separate state for your `products` array and for the active `index`. And I'm not sure why you want to use `ref`s here.

When you render the list of images, you can check if the currently rendered index is the same as the `activeIndex` in your state. If it is, add the `active` class name, if not, don't add anything. You don't need to store the previously selected index because when you map over the images, you only set the class for the selected one.

```
const ProductDetails = () => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    {
      _id: "1",
      title: "Nike Shoes",
      src: [
        "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2021/01/07/img2.png",
        "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2021/01/07/img3.png",
        "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2021/01/07/img4.png",
      ],
    },
  ]);

  return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          {products.map((item) => (
            <Colsm6 key={item._id}>
              <ProductdetailsPic>
                <Sync1>
                  <Item>
                    <img src={item.src[activeIndex]} alt="" />
                  </Item>
                </Sync1>
                <Sync2>
                  {item.src.map((img, i) => (
                    <Item>
                      <Itempro>
                        <img
                          src={img}
                          className={i === activeIndex ? 'active' : null}
                          alt=""
                          onClick={() => setActiveIndex(i)}
                        />
                      </Itempro>
                    </Item>
                  ))}
                </Sync2>
              </ProductdetailsPic>
            </Colsm6>
          ))}
          <Prosdetleft></Prosdetleft>
        </Row>
      </Container>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```